# Bar graph not working

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Using this code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
          \begin{axis}[
               ybar,
                bar width=.5cm,
                width=0.48\textwidth,
                height=.5\textwidth,
                symbolic x coords={\xcoords},
                xtick=data,
                nodes near coords,
                nodes near coords align={vertical},
                ymin=0,ymax=50,
                ylabel={\%},
            ]
            \addplot  table[x=column 1,y=column 2,col sep=comma] {cfets.csv}; 

          \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the input coordinate `8' has not been defined 
with 'symbolic x coords={8,14,24,4,15,19,13,23,18,5,1,3,11,2,7,17,20}... Maybe 
it has been misspelled?.
```

I have this set up such that any time I update my results, it automatically updates a .sty and a .csv file with those results, making it easy modify. As is probably obvious, the \xcoords is a .sty command that, in this case, just writes:

```
\newcommand*{\xcoords}{8,14,24,4,15,19,13,23,18,5,1,3,11,2,7,17,20}
```

and the cfets.csv file has two columns, looking like this:

```
column 1    column 2
8   44
14  44
24  44
4   20
15  17
19  16
13  13
23  13
18  12
5   10
1   4
3   2
11  2
2   1
7   1
17  1
20  1
```

commas removed because I copy+pasted from excel.

What is going on?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you tried without `symbolic x coords`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `xticklabels from table` instead, to get the ticklabels from the data file.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents} % this is just for example, the environment below writes its contents to the specified file
\begin{filecontents*}{cfets.csv}
column1 column2 % note changed column headings (removed spaces)
8  44
14 44
24 44
4  20
15 17
19 16
13 13
23 13
18 12
5  10
1  4
3  2
11 2
2  1
7  1
17 1
20 1
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[
           ybar,
            bar width=.4cm, % modified
            enlarge x limits={abs=.4cm}, % added
            width=0.8\textwidth, % modified
            height=.5\textwidth,
            xtick=data,
            xticklabels from table={cfets.csv}{column1}, % added
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords align={vertical},
            ymin=0,ymax=50,
            ylabel={\%},
        ]
        % node x expr=\coordindex instead of x=
        \addplot  table[x expr=\coordindex,y=column2] {cfets.csv}; 

      \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the fast response!

To avoid the possibility of missing a space somewhere, I changed the column headers to "fets" and "counts" instead of "column1" and "column2". Then I get this error:

Sorry, could not retrieve column 'fets' from table 'cfets.csv'. Please check spelling (or introduce name aliases)..

this didn't work when using column 1 or column1 either :-/

Comment: @normalice Did you use a comma to separate the columns? Doesn't look like that works if you put a filename in `xticklabels from table`, but you can do `\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{cfets.csv}\datatable`, and then `xticklabels from table={\datatable}{column1}`, if using a space is not an option.

Comment: Sweet. That did it. Thank you :-)